# Pandas replace Chunk of rows by a Chunk of different size

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given an arbitrary dataframe such as

```
df = pd.DataFrame([10,8,6,4,2])
>>> df
    0
0  10
1   8
2   6
3   4
4   2
```

I would like to replace a chunk of this dataset with a chunk of different size:

```
new_chunk = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,1])
>>> df.iloc[[0,1]]
    0
0  10
1   8
df.iloc[[0,1]].replace_chunk(new_chunk)
>>> df
    0
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   1
2   6
3   4
4   2
```

Is there any single command (`replace_chunk` does not exist, I want to mimmick his behaviour) to perform this operation? Maybe with multiple commands?

Comment: isn't the output you got what you want ?

Comment: The function `replace_chunk` does not exist. I just made it up to show behaviour. Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with 3 DataFrames - first values before first values of positions, then new and last values after:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([10,8,6,4,2])
new_chunk = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,1])

pos = [0, 1]
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:pos[0]], new_chunk, df.iloc[pos[-1]:]], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   0
0  1
1  1
2  1
3  1
4  8
5  6
6  4
7  2
```

---

```
pos = [2, 4]
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:pos[0]], new_chunk, df.iloc[pos[-1]:]], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
    0
0  10
1   8
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   2
```

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Simple and concise.

Answer (score 2):

try with this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([10,8,6,4,2])

new_chunk = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,1])
df = df[df.iloc[[0,1]].shape[0]:]
df = pd.concat([new_chunk,df],axis=0)
print(df)
```

output :

```
   0
0  1
1  1
2  1
3  1
2  6
3  4
4  2
```